# Unable to load crlnumber when creating CRL with OpenSSL

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl

I am trying to create a CRL with my own private CA with OpenSSL. I have to work on a Windows machine from the binary. I give the command:

```
$openssl ca -gencrl -config root-ca.conf -out root-ca.crl
```

which gives me the error:

```
unable to load number from root-ca/db/crlnumber
error while loading CRL number
20192:error:0D066096:asn1 encoding routines:a2i_ASN1_INTEGER:short line:crypto\asn1\f_int.c:151:
error in ca
```

I use the config from https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html# ,but I changed the home = ca-root under [ca_default], s.t. it fits my directory.

The file crlnumber exists (in the given path) and contains just 01. All answers I have found so far recommend that. I have also tried 1001. But it does not work for me. I am very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you create the file with a Windows tool like notepad, wordpad, or Word? If so it may contain an invisible but harmful "BOMb" (actually Unicode Byte Order Mark) which OpenSSL cannot handle. Try using notepad with 'ANSI' encoding, or 'DOS-mode' `edit` if 32bit. Or if you can copy the file _exactly_ (NOT cut&paste) to a Unix system, look at it there with `cat -v` or `od -tx1` or `xxd` or any tool that displays all bytes. If you have only Windows, run `openssl base64 <crlnumber` and post the result (which is printable and cut&pastable by design) for us to check.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I used the echo command in the Powershell console. The data should be ANSI encoded, as this is the default. The base64 encrypted form is MDE=   when I decrypt that again it shows 01. So I guess the file is in order. Remark: I had to use the -in command. <crlnumber does not work for some reason. "extra arguments given. base64: Use -help for summary. error in base64" Thank you for your time!

Comment: (1) Yes, MDE= encodes 01 with no BOM. Also no line ending, which is unusual, but as I read the code I think _should_ be okay; it does work correctly for me, using several recent ShiningLight builds on my Windows system (which in turn use the MSVC libraries), although the _updated_ file has LF added. But you might try adding either LF or CRLF to see if it makes any difference. (2) `<file` (and `>file` and `>>file`) is used in Unix shells and Windows CMD for redirection; you didn't mention PS and even if you had I am much less familiar with it. It might be worth rechecking with CMD.